# How to plot the 3rd column using the other two columns as axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following DataFrame:

| ... | ... | CPU Utilization % | CPU Temperature °С | dif (CPU Utilization - CPU Temperature) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | 10.913399 | 9.727057 | 10.913399 - 9.727057 |
| ... | ... | 14.230935 | 12.561181 | 14.230935 - 12.561181 |
| etc |  |  |  |  |

I want to plot df['dif'] and use as x-values 'CPU Utilization %' and y-values - 'CPU Temperature °С':
[image]

I tried do

```
df['dif'].plot(kind='scatter', x='util', y='temp')
```

but it says:

> ValueError: plot kind scatter can only be used for data frames

How can i plot graph?

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='util', y='temp', hue='diff')`

Comment: Agree for the usage of Seaborn. Btw your error is linked to the fact that `df[column]` returns a `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was already suggested in the comment attached to your question by [@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang), I will suggest you to do it with a scatter plot with the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org) library, such as:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='util', y='temp', hue='diff')
```

The `hue` argument enables to rank them according to the `'diff'` value, as a "third dimension".